# Categorization strategy on Magento CE

Tags: magento, attributes, organization, categorization

I'm currently defining my products categorization on Magento CE.

Our catalog is huge and we have many custom attributes allready defined (gender, type, color).
I need now to create the categories.

The Customer should browse the catalog by differents ways.

Example 1, The Customer interested by a "type 1" product for woman, he will have 2 mains routes to access that information:
1) Go to "type 1" category (click on mainmenu), then check the attribute woman in gender attribute (layered navigation on the left). The url rendered will be www.myshop.com/type-1.html. For that cas I'll not be able to define a static block for this "type-1/woman" display (banner top of the products listing).
2) Go to "type 1" and sublink "woman" (on the mainmenu). Now the landing page is different, the url produced is www.myshop.com/type-1/woman.html. But I'll be able to define some specific static block to that category.

With that it mind, I think I'll have to create 1st categories level based on type, then on each type, I'll create a subcategory level for "gender", then on each gender category, I'll have to create categories based on "colors" on other attributes.

Is that the right way to deal with categories? 
Or should I manage it by an another way (less seo friendly), this one for example: http://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

Note: I've bought a lot of books on mangento but any of them give a specific formation on that kind of requirements...

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to handle this, my recommendation is to use anchor categories (category layered navigation) in conjunction with attribute layered nav.     The trick is with landing pages which I can see you are experiencing.  Which attributes do you desire to have landing pages for?  I am not familiar with your products but an idea would be to have a category structure of

Anything non-anchor will have a landing page. Once an anchor is set,  that will be the last landing page a customer will see.

Basically if someone clicks through the top nav and goes directly to shirts,  they will see a shirts landing page,   if they go through top nav and go directly to womens they will see a womens landing page,  however given the below setup if they start on women,  and then go to shirts the landing page will remain womens.   because they landed on womens first and created the anchor point for layered navigation.   Configurations typically should be left as attributes like color, size, inseam, etc. etc.  Things like Womens, Mens,   Shirts, Jeans,  or a particular trend typically should be categories because they should typically have landing pages.

In a lot of ways layered attribute navigation and category layered navigation (anchor categories) can be used interchangeably however, each has its benefit.

I believe that mens and womens apparel should be anchor categories

```
Mens (anchor)

Womens (anchor)  

   Shirts (anchor)
   Jeans  (anchor)
```

I will refine this answer once you fill me in with more details of your product types and areas that you wish to have landing pages.

Comment: Hi Rob. First of all, thank you for your detailed answer. 
Thinking "landing page" really helps to define the categories. 

I've multiple scenarios that can help to define the better strategy. 

Scenario 1: I need to produce specific landing pages for man/woman/unisexe products (root categories I guess) and also for subcategories like man>shirts, man>jeans, woman>jeans, woman>dress.
But I'm not sure what would be the best root categories. "gender" or "types"? create woman/man/unisexe as first level, and on each category, create sub-categories based on type (jeans, dress, etc)?

Comment: Scenario 2: I also need to produce direct access to brand pages, with specific static block or banner displayed over the products list (setting in the category options in backend). You need to know that "custom_manufacturer" is a custom attribute allready managed. But to produce that kind of "landing page" (and SEO friendly url), I did not have choice to manually create the related categories and dispatch the products inside them.

Comment: This scenario made me think: how the other stores manager deals with that? Maybe I need to work with an extension that can produce "landing" page without obligation to create the category (like it is explained under "Custom meta tags for pages with selected attributes": http://amasty.com/improved-navigation-seo-layered-navigation.html).

Comment: I would be able to define man>jeans landing page with pre-selected attribute gender:"man" + type:"jeans".
If that kind of extension is not relevant, I will have to deal with a lot of categories...

What is your opinion?

Comment: I would create both gender and types as categories.  They both should be set as anchor.   Type in my opinion should not be an attribute.

Comment: What do you think about "improved layered navigation" extension? It should be a way to create easily custom landing pages based on attributes...

Comment: That's an option,  however I try and stay away from custom functionality if possible.   Magento typically accommodates for most scenarios out of the box, and I don't like to reinvent functionality that already exists. Dealing with categories is usually relatively simple.  If you make changes at the product level or through mass actions managing larger numbers of categories are typically not an issue.

Comment: Do you have a tip for mass "linking" products to categories? Like the bulk update for attributes (in catalog products grid).

Comment: In the admin top nav,  go to catalog->manage categories  Once this opens select the category you wish to add products to then on the top right tab select category products.   You will then see a list of containing products,  there is a small dropdown that offers "any", "yes" and "no" as available options. Select "no" and click search,  this will show you all products not in this category.  Using the checkmarks select the products you wish to add to the category and then click save.

Comment: Thank you for that great tip! One more question regarding the categories. Do I need to create the categories tree for each site view? If not, can I translate the category "seo friendly url" for each view?

Comment: Are you referring to a multi-language store?   If so, to be honest I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. I guess I can manage the category "URL Key" value for each language with switching the "Store view" (select liste top left of the page). Then for each store view I can define specific URL Key value.